# slow algorithm contest

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve an [SPOJ contest](http://www.spoj.com/) asking "are two words are anagrams?". I reduced it to 4 lines and it's still too slow.

```
while STDIN.gets
  y = $_.downcase.split
  if (y[0].chars.to_a.sort == y[1].chars.to_a.sort) then puts "YES" else puts "NO" end
end
```

Comment: Include the code here.

Comment: What do you mean by `too slow` It is pretty fast when I tried it.

Comment: i got error about it at spoj platform, it must be faster i guess

Comment: Don't guess.  What was the actual error message?

Comment: Could you give me spoj link?

Comment: The problem is likely "my code runs in a split second, but the contest requires me to run in a split nano-second, on their machine. Can you guys help me win this contest?"

Comment: error about time limit, hmm its private contest
I/O
    AlFa aalf
    raz dwa
    grrr rrg
~
  YES
  NO
  NO

Comment: The `to_a`'s are redundant, `chars` returns an array of the characters.

Comment: Fewer lines of code does not mean faster performance.

Comment: without to_a still timelimit..

Comment: @user3626424 `to_a` is actually redundant, so remove it

Comment: Benchmarking shows a slight speedup using Ruby's conditional expression: `puts y[0].chars.sort == y[1].chars.sort ? "TAK" : "NIE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK, you might make it faster by checking the words have the same length before the actual sort:

```
while !STDIN.gets.chomp.empty?
  first_word, second_word = $_.downcase.split
  if first_word.length == second_word.length && 
    first_word.chars.sort == second_word.chars.sort
    puts "YES" 
  else 
    puts "NO" 
  end
end
```

Comment: Benchmarking shows this has a substantial speedup when the words are different lengths, vs. a very slight penalty when they're the same length.